# handleWatchKitExtensionRequest not responding to openParentApplication in Watchkit Extension (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos

I am trying to send information from my WatchKit App over to my main parent application and from what I understand I should just be able to use `openParentApplication` in my watchkit Extension which will be received by `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` in AppDelegate.swift, but I cant seem to get `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` to be triggered.

I've been having some issues, so at this point I'm just trying to establish any connection at all before worrying about what information is actually passed. so currently in my Watchkit ViewController I have the following:

```
 let testDict = [
    "value1" : "Test 1",
    "value2" : "Test 2"
]

@IBAction func saveButtonFunction() {
    openParentAppForBalance(testDict)
}

private func openParentAppForInfo(Dict: [String: String]) {

    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(testDict,
        reply: {(reply, error) -> Void in
            println("openParentApplication called in button function")
    })
}
```

which shows in the output that the function is being called, but `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` just wont respond. Currently it's set to the following in AppDelegate.swift which never gets called:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

    println("we made it!")

    var retValues = Dictionary<String,String>()

    retValues["retval1"] = "return Test 1"
    retValues["retval1"] = "return Test 2"

    reply(retValues)

}
```

I'm sure I'm probably just missing something really fundamental here in my understanding of how this all works, but any help at all about how to get `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` to be triggered would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ah, I think what is happening here is that your code is both correct, and working exactly as it should, and what you're interpreting here is a result of an overlap of two entirely understandable assumptions, that are actually not correct and have been leading you astray. So the good news is, your code is already working.

You say,

> ...which shows in the output that the function is being called...

If by that you mean that in the console you are seeing the message, `openParentApplication called in button function`, then here's what is going on:

This part of your code is a Swift Closure:

```
{(reply, error) -> Void in
        println("openParentApplication called in button function")
}
```

When your WatchKit Extension calls `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication` it passes to your parent iPhone app a dictionary (your `testDict`), which the iPhone application can use to return data to you—providing the data has been serialized. It also returns back to you the closure that you passed it. This enables your WatchKit Extension to run code that it has itself defined, at the later point when the reply has been received. You can include in this closure use of both the returned data in the `testDict` and also other variables that were locally accessible at the time `openParentApplication` was called. Your WatchKit Extension automatically executes the code in the closure when it is received back.

So when you see `openParentApplication called in button function`, this indicates that the *reply* from the iPhone application has been received, and the closure has been executed. Therefore, your WatchKit test code should really change the println statement to be:

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(testDict,
    reply: {(reply, error) -> Void in
        println("Reply to openParentApplication received from iPhone app")
    })
```

Now, the reason why you quite understandably didn't realise the code was executing correctly was because you were expecting to see rejected in the console that this code had been executed in your iPhone app:

```
println("we made it!")
```

However, Xcode does not support attaching to two processes simultaneously. Therefore, when you are attached to your WatchKit app, you will not see any log messages of your iPhone app. Your iPhone app also will not respond to breakpoints when it is not the attached process. Both of these are true whether it is running in the background (woken by `openParentApplication`) or running in the foreground (if you launch it manually in the simulator after the WatchKit app has been run. You can see the effects of the iPhone app activity, but cannot directly introspect it while you are attached to the WatchKit app.

So firstly, your code is working correctly. You can move past your test code! And in relation to introspecting the workings in the iPhone side when it is responding to your WatchKit app, there is a partial solution. Launch the WatchKit app from the simulator, and once it is running, in Xcode activate the menu option **Debug > Attach to process...** and select your iPhone app process under **Likely targets** at the top. Now you will see your iPhone app console messages and your iPhone app will respond to breakpoints—but of course you will no longer see these from the WatchKit app side. You continue to be able to interact with both apps in the simulators, and can swap back and forth between which one you are attached to during execution.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! selecting my iPhone app under likely targets still doesn't seem to be showing me the output from the iPhone app (in fact it doesn't show any output at all) but I made a partial solution for a partial solution by passing '`.description`' back as an item in the reply for each thing I wanted to show and printed them in the Watchkit Extension output. but everything is now working perfectly - thanks for the help!

Comment: For a code example on how to use the background mode, which ensures that the main app has time to send its reply, refer to "Calling parent application from Watch app" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000274/calling-parent-application-from-watch-app/30000323#30000323)

Comment: One important point: Xcode can attach to multiple processes at the same time for debugging this: After starting the Watch Kit App, in the iPhone Simulator click on your main app's icon (to start it) and then go back to Xcode. In the menu bar in the 'debug' menu, select 'attach to process' and select your main app. Now you are debugging both, your Watch Kit Extension and your main app!

Comment: Ups, just saw the second answer.. nvm.

Answer (score 15):

Just a side note, you actually can attach to two processes simultaneously in Xcode and it's very useful for debugging WatchKit.  Build and run your WatchKit Extension target from Xcode and it'll start running in the simulator.  Now, in the simulator, launch your iOS app.  With that running, go to Debug->Attach to Process->[Name of your app process].  Now you'll see both processes running in Xcode and you'll be able to log, debug, etc... across both.

Comment: Is it not the case that attaching to one process detaches from the other? It has been my experience that you can swap between processes during a session, but not see log statements etc from them simultaneously. Perhaps I've missed something/missed a recent change?

Comment: I can not see log from the main app when using println("Debug"). How can you see log after attaching the main app to XCode Debug?

Comment: I can confirm that indeed, debugging two processes as described above indeed works and I was able to step through both my watch kit extension and companion app when I fired off "openParent".