# Parent handleWatchKitExtensionRequest never called?

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit

I have read a few questions/answers before asking, and also attached process, but does not seem to work.

My watchkit extension is written in Swift, and the AppDelegate is in Objective-C (since it is old code).

In my extension, I called:

```
@IBAction func toPage2() {
    println("to page 2")
    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["page":"2"], reply: {(reply, error) -> Void in })
}
```

In my AppDelegate, I tried printing

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
NSLog(@"handle watchkit");

NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page2"] ofType:@"wav"];
AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:file] error:nil];
[audio play];
...
```

I have also tried Debug > Attach to process and choose the iPhone app, and still nothing happened. Can anyone points me to a direction?

Comment: Does this problem occur also in the simulator when the main iPhone app is active? Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000274/calling-parent-application-from-watch-app

Answer (score 1):

Start a background task in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:). This ensures that the main app on the iPhone is not suspended (when the app on the iPhone is not active) before it can send its reply.

**Code in the app delegate of the main app on iPhone:**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void ( ^)( NSDictionary * ))reply
{
   __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;
   watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask"
                                                               expirationHandler:^{
                                                                 watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                                                               }];

   if ( [[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"getData"] )
   {
      // get data
      // ...
      reply( data );
   }

   dispatch_after( dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 1 ), dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 ), ^{
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register for background mode Audio and then take your code and wrap it in a `UIBackgroundTask`  Also you need to return a `reply()` as part of your `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`

Here is a good link on [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: You do not need to register for a background mode. This will cause your app to be potentially rejected if you aren't playing background audio.

Comment: You are using `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` which will launch your app into the background if it is not already running in the foreground.

Comment: I am running the app in foreground... nothing prints out, nothing plays.