# How to open the app when someone clicks something on an Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am making an Apple Watch app. One of the buttons will open the iphone app connected to the watch app.

What code do I use to do this?

I don't know what to even try?

Note: I am using swift for this project.

Answer (score 1):

WatchKit doesn't include the ability to open the host iOS app in the foreground. The best you can do is open it in the background using `openParentApplication:reply:`.

If you *need* the user to do something in your iOS app, consider making use of Handoff.

Comment: Whats a handoff. Please elaborate?

Comment: @nachshonfertel some info about handoff here; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/HandoffFundamentals/HandoffFundamentals.html You should searched this for yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to launch a call on the iphone?

Comment: @nachshonfertel search for it on the internet. Show some effort.

Comment: I did, but i got no answer. Please help.

Comment: @nachshonfertel There's a link here in the comments start there. SO isn't here to hold your hand every step of the way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to activate an inactive iPhone app from the Watch. It is, however, possible to call the iPhone app to perform a task or to ask for data. See here: [Calling parent application from Watch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000274/calling-parent-application-from-watch-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can only open the iPhone app in the background by the following method:

Swift:

```
openParentApplication([ParentApp], reply:[Reply])
```

Objective-C:

```
openParentApplication:reply:
```

There is no ability to open the parent app in the foreground.

Note: To send data to iOS app in the background, use the first method.

Note: According to bgilham,

> If you need the user to do something in your iOS app, consider making use of Handoff.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to open your parent app in the foreground, use Handoff!**

**https://developer.apple.com/handoff/**

**Example**:

Somewhere shared for both:

```
static let sharedUserActivityType = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.youraction"
static let sharedIdentifierKey = "identifier"
```

on your Watch:

```
updateUserActivity(sharedUserActivityType, userInfo: [sharedIdentifierKey : 123456], webpageURL: nil)
```

on your iPhone in App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool {
    if (userActivityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]!) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if (userActivity.activityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        if let userInfo = userActivity.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let identifier = userInfo[sharedIdentifierKey] as? Int {
                //Do something
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Handoff", message: "Handoff has been triggered for identifier \(identifier)" , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Thanks for the info!")
                alert.show()
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**And finally (this step is important!!!): In your Info.plist(s)**

[image]