# WatchKit return reply() inside a block in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000274/calling-parent-application-from-watch-app?lq=1) SO post where apparently data was being fetched and returned to the Watch extension like so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void ( ^)( NSDictionary * ))reply
{
  if ( [[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"getData"] )
 {
  // get data
  // ...
  reply( data );
 }
}
```

But when I try to call 'reply()' inside a block after getting network data like so:

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;

watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask"
                                                               expirationHandler:^{
                                                                   watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                                                               }];   
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void ( ^)( NSDictionary * ))reply
{ 

NSMutableDictionary *response = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[ClassObject getDataWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
        
        if (succeeded)
        {
            [response setObject:@"update succeded" forKey:@"updateKey"];
            reply(response);
            
        }
        else
        {
            if (error)
            {
                [response setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update failed: %@", error.description] forKey:@"updateKey"]; 
                reply(response);
            }
            else
            {
                [response setObject:@"update failed with no error" forKey:@"updateKey"];
                reply(response);
            }
        }
    }];
}

dispatch_after(dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 180), dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
});
```

I get this error:

> "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]"

So I guess I have to call reply() immediately and the only way to send fresh network data after WatchKit wakes up the parent app is to use MMWormhole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that your asynchronous data fetch does not return immediately (without calling reply), you may try the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void ( ^)( NSDictionary * ))reply
{ 
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;

    watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask"
                                                               expirationHandler:^{
                                                                   watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                                                               }];  

   NSMutableDictionary *response = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

   dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

   [ClassObject getDataWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){

        if (succeeded)
        {
            [response setObject:@"update succeded" forKey:@"updateKey"];
            reply(response);

        }
        else
        {
            if (error)
            {
                [response setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update failed: %@", error.description] forKey:@"updateKey"]; 

                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

                reply(response);
            }
            else
            {
                [response setObject:@"update failed with no error" forKey:@"updateKey"];

                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

                reply(response);
            }
        }
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 1), dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
  });
}
```

Comment: I already was wrapping it in a background task.  I should have made this clear and have updated my question.  I even tried changing the time to 180 seconds but it still returns immediately with the error.  Do you run a block in 'get data' in your example?

Comment: Hello, I have changed my answer accordingly. In this way, one second is enough since the program waits at `dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` until `dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);` is executed. Does it work?

Comment: it's not working for me. I did the same. Just doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your code mixed up. You need to move the `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` to be inside your `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` Make it the first thing you do, then call your function.

Simplified example:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply{


    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask __block = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"watchAppRequest" expirationHandler:^{

        NSLog(@"Background handler called. Background tasks expirationHandler called.");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    }];

    //do your background task(s) here
    if([requestString isEqualToString:@“myRequest"]){

            //send reply back to watch
            reply();
    }

    //end background task
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always refer to official documentation. [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

The following code works for me.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
                // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
                // stopped or ending the task outright.
                [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

// Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

    [ClassObject getDataWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){

        if (succeeded)
        {
            [response setObject:@"update succeded" forKey:@"updateKey"];
            reply(response);

        }
        else
        {
            if (error)
            {
                [response setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update failed: %@", error.description] forKey:@"updateKey"]; 

                reply(response);
            }
            else
            {
                [response setObject:@"update failed with no error" forKey:@"updateKey"];

                reply(response);
            }
        }
    }];
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```