# iOS openParentApplication is not waking up parent application

Tags: ios, watchkit

In my watch app, I am using `openParentApplication` to communicate with the parent app however this is not always reliable especially if I have not used the parent app for a while.  It seems that this is not waking up the parent app for communication. If I tap the parent app and launch it however, two way communication proceeds as normal and I get all my data. There are no crashes of any sort. The code is very sound.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Have you initiated a background task? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137019/watchkit-return-reply-inside-a-block-in-handlewatchkitextensionrequest

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you create a background task in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`. If you don't know how to do this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137019/watchkit-return-reply-inside-a-block-in-handlewatchkitextensionrequest) is an example.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone.  I appreciate it.  I was looking into the background task comments and I came across a problem with this call: [[UIApplication sharedApplication].  I have to allow the Watch Extension target for AppDelegate in order to enable the two-way communication however watch kit does not allow the usage of [[UIApplication sharedApplication].  So I'm not exactly sure how people are accomplishing this.

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` is used in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`, which is a method in the app delegate of the parent application, not of the watch extension/app.

Comment: I have implemented this in my code and am testing.  Many Thanks!