# is it possible to share text from apple watch app?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, apple-watch, whatsapp

I wants to share some text from my apple watch application to social media OR messaging apps . I found something from here -  [presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH19-SW1)

I can able to show my text but not getting option to share my text like we found in **UIactivityviewcontroller or share extension**  .

Comment: Currently, that feature is not available in WatchKit.

Answer (score 0):

The method `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:` is useful to input text, for example by using voice input or by choosing from a list of suggestions.

If you want to share the selected text with someone else, send it to the iPhone app using the method `openParentApplication...` (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000274/how-do-i-correctly-call-the-parent-application-from-my-watch-app-so-that-the-bac/30000323#30000323)). Then on the iPhone, you have many possibilities that WatchKit currently does not offer.