# Getting WebService response from Block to WatchKit App

Tags: ios, web-services, swift, watchkit

I'm currently working on making one app compatible with AppleWatch,

For that I'm calling one WebService, the problem is  I'm getting WebService response in Block, and **reply()** block is not getting called there showing error.

Error,

```
The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]
```

My Appdelegate,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

    getInfo(userInfo, reply: reply)

}

func getInfo(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) ->Void)!){

    let dicParam:NSDictionary = [:]

    let wsfr:WSFrameWork = WSFrameWork(URLAndParams:WS_GET_DATA, dicParams: dicParam as [NSObject : AnyObject])

    wsfr.isLogging = false

    wsfr.onError = { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
        reply(nil)
    }

    wsfr.onSuccess = { (dicResponse : Dictionary!) -> Void in

        if dicResponse["data"] != nil{

            let returnData = ["Returned NSData":dicResponse]
            reply(returnData)

        }

    }
}
```

WSFrameWork is our WebService framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got my answer by doing Sync WS request,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

    getCurrentDataInfo(userInfo, reply: reply)

}

func getCurrentDataInfo(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) ->Void)!){

    var data = parseJSON(getJSON("https://My_JSON_URL"))

    println(data)

    reply(["myData":data])

}

func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}

func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary{
    var error: NSError?
    var boardsDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

    return boardsDictionary
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the method `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` is not finishing before the OS kills it. Therefore:

- Explicitly create a background task.
- If you want to fetch data asynchroneously, ensure that the method `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` is not left before the background fetch has been finished.

Here is a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000274/how-do-i-correctly-call-the-parent-application-from-my-watch-app-so-that-the-bac/30000323#30000323) that shows how to implement the above.